# Can I tell mikro to add a trigger to a table?

Tags: mikro-orm

I would like to put a trigger on a database table to create a log entry every time one of the columns changes. Roughly:

```sql
create function update_status_log() returns trigger as $update_status_log$
  begin
    -- details elided
  end;
$update_status_log$ language plpgsql;

create or replace trigger log_new_status
  after insert or update on my_table
  for each row execute function update_status_log();
```

I don't see any way to tell mikro that I want that trigger and function to exist. I can manually add them to the migration that creates the status log table, but that won't affect the schema generator (which we use in tests) and it may be difficult for future maintainers to understand how data gets into that table.

For practical purposes, mikro's `BeforeCreate` and `BeforeUpdate` lifecycle hooks will probably suffice. But the database triggers would have certain upsides (e.g. you don't have to initialize entities to make them work). Is there any way to have mikro manage these things?

Comment: You could add them in a migration file, as there you can add any arbitrary SQL. The schema diffing will ignore triggers. There were some proposals to handle the triggers as well, which indeed makes sense.